# Comparing two websites in two windows using selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I need to test two websites using selenium webdriver on python. My goal is to make and save changes on one website and then see if the other website changed content accordingly. I want to make a change, then switch to a different window with a different website, then back and forth multiple times. Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: @JeffC The person has asked for a logic to implement his task. I am not sure what you expect him to share.

Comment: @LINGS I expect everyone that asks a question on SO to do their homework. They should spend some time googling for an answer to their own question and try something, anything on their own. SO is not a coding service where people come ask questions and we provide code. If you read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you will see these principles stated. I have seen questions on SO dealing with switching between windows. They should start there and write some basic code and keep adding to it until they get stuck. They post their code and ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a new window by `driver.execute_script("window.open('');")` and then switch to it by `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])` then you can drive it. If you want to switch back to first window `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])`.

```
>>> driver.window_handles
[u'{7355ca99-910b-554d-8478-f8a550e0c767}']
>>> driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
>>> driver.window_handles
[u'{7355ca99-910b-554d-8478-f8a550e0c767}', u'{5a0824a9-9d55-0841-87b8-35a26d4a8b83}']
>>> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
>>> driver.get("http://www.google.com")
>>> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
>>> driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, just switch between windows using proper commands in selenium webdriver.

If you want to compare graphical elements it's a really good idea to automate it.

For how to navigate between windows look here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html