# send an address to the newly opened tab through selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open a new tab and copy a new URL address to it

I currently am able to open a New tab by `body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')`

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    #time.sleep(2)  #wait 1 second
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

However I am not sure how to copy a new address to the URL

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("").send_keys("https://google.com/")
```

But was not sure what to have inside link text

any suggestions?

**Why not a duplicate:**

Question is what goes inside the `find_element_by_link_text("")`. The page sent as duplicate only says urlLink. What does that mean ?

Comment: Almost the same issue you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33104738/2568849) for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @DmitryMalinovsky please see my edit

Comment: Thanks, you may find your answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohamad.

This is how you can do it in java:

1) YOu go to Gmail homepage (baseURL)

```
   public void goToLoginPage() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/intl/en/mail/help/about.html");
    driver.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();
}
```

2) Here you open a new tab, by sending the selectLinkOpeninNewTab key combination (CTRL + T) to xpath("html") element. And then you simply navigate to another link (facebook in my case)

```
       public void openNewTab() throws InterruptedException {
   String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+ "t");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
    driver.navigate().to("https://facebook.com");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

}
```

I think it would be easy for you to convert it in Python

Answer (score -2):

The link [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver) that was posted as a comment to your question does indeed specify what goes into the link_text element. Look at the answers.
Also, `driver.get("someurl")` should also work, just like how you navigated to a url when you launched the driver. I just tested it and it worked perfectly